# AngularJs leaflet directive map not rendering correctly on mobile with ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary, ionic-framework, directive

I recently started to give Ionic a go and I use [Angular Leaflet Directive](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/). for the geolocation to display

All is okay, but I have a problem what I am not able to resolve.

Everything is working on pc.

But on mobile the paths are not showing up, and the map is gray

[image]

My Cotroller

```
.controller('ShowCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $http, leafletData) {

  $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Downloading...'});

  $scope.center = {};
  $scope.paths = {};
  $scope.markers = {};
  $scope.defaults = {};
  $scope.map = {};

    $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/'+$stateParams.id,
     params: {
          'client_id'     : 'xxx',
          'client_secret' : 'xxx',
          'v'             : '20130815',
        }
  }).then(function successCallback(data) {
      $timeout(function () {

         $scope.place = data.data.response.venue;
         $scope.title = data.data.response.venue.name;

            angular.extend($scope, {
                center: {
                    lat: $scope.lat,
                    lng:  $scope.long,
                    zoom: 12
                },
                paths: {
                    p1: {
                        color: '#ff612f',
                        weight: 5,
                        latlngs: [
                            { lat: data.data.response.venue.location.lat, lng: data.data.response.venue.location.lng },
                            { lat: $scope.lat, lng: $scope.long }
                        ],
                    }
                },
                markers: {
                    destination: {
                        lat: data.data.response.venue.location.lat,
                        lng: data.data.response.venue.location.lng,
                        message: data.data.response.venue.name,
                        focus: true,
                        draggable: false,
                        icon: {
                            iconUrl: 'lib/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon2.png',
                        }
                    },
                    mylocation: {
                        lat: $scope.lat,
                        lng:  $scope.long,
                        icon: {
                            iconUrl: 'lib/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
                        }
                    }
                },
                defaults: {
                    scrollWheelZoom: false,
                    zoomControl:false 
                }
            });
          $ionicLoading.hide();
     }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Map

```
<leaflet id="map" center="center" paths="paths"  markers="markers" defaults="defaults"></leaflet>
```

Could please someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem was that i had to initialize tileLayer before the ajax call

like this

```
$scope.defaults = { zoomControl: false, layerControl: false, tileLayer: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'};

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/'+$stateParams.id,
     params: {
          'client_id'     : 'xxx',
          'client_secret' : 'xxx',
          'v'             : '20130815',
        }
  }).then(function successCallback(data) {
      $timeout(function () {

         $scope.place = data.data.response.venue;
         $scope.title = data.data.response.venue.name;

            angular.extend($scope, {
                markers: {
                    destination: {
                        lat: data.data.response.venue.location.lat,
                        lng: data.data.response.venue.location.lng,
                        message: data.data.response.venue.name,
                        focus: true,
                        draggable: false,
                        icon: {
                            iconUrl: 'lib/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon2.png',
                        }
                    },
                    mylocation: {
                        lat: $scope.lat,
                        lng:  $scope.long,
                        icon: {
                            iconUrl: 'lib/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
          $ionicLoading.hide();
     }, 2000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Cordova version are you using?

A recent version now forces the use of [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). Because of this, you have to allow each and every HTTP request you make.

Leaflet tiles are fetched from the web, so you have to allow them.

The [standard & recommended meta](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy) for this is:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`

Just include this line in the `head` of your HTML, and it should work better.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and sorry for the slow answer, but same result

Comment: Ok, then can you please use the command `adb shell logcat | grep CONSOLE` while your device is USB connected to your PC, to see what the error message is, if any?